# axis_conversion producing unexpected result?

Tags: scripting, coordinates, matrix

I am attempting to convert the world transforms of scene objects into a different coordinate system (-Z forward Y up) using axis_conversion method as follows:

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import axis_conversion
import mathutils

m = axis_conversion(from_forward='Y', 
        from_up='Z',
        to_forward='-Z',
        to_up='Y').to_4x4()

for obj in bpy.context.selectable_objects:
    print(obj.name + "-----------------------------------")
    print(obj.matrix_world)
    nm = m * obj.matrix_world
    print(nm)
    #obj.matrix_world = nm
```

This produces the following output:

```
OilDrum_low.005-----------------------------------
<Matrix 4x4 (0.0100,  0.0000,  0.0000, 17.0000)
            (0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0100, 20.2891)
            (0.0000,  0.0100, -0.0000,  2.1153)
            (0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (0.0100,  0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0100, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, -0.0100, -0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

The calculated matrices do not appear to have any of the translation data. Did I mix something up while doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that in version 3.5 python introduced a matrix multiplication operator `@`, and I was unaware you had to use this syntax instead of the normal multiplication operator `*`. Changing this line:

```
nm = m * obj.matrix_world
```

to this

```
nm = m @ obj.matrix_world
```

resolves issue and I now receive results as expected.